# How to decide concurrency number in Sidekiq for CPU/RAM expensive jobs?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, sidekiq

I have a Rails 4 application in Heroku which uses [Sidekiq](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq) as a background job processor. The job basically does two things (which are CPU/RAM expensive):

- Parse sites using [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/)
- Do some image manipulation with [Rmagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/RMagick)

By default Sidekiq comes with a concurrency of 25 threads per process, but if I have that concurrency, I exceed the memory quota of my worker dyno. When doing 10 threads per process I get more or less this:

```
Process running mem=936M(182.8%)
Error R14 (Memory quota exceeded)
```

So, I could low the numbers of threads to 2 or 3 in order to make sure that I will 'never' overcome the memory allowed by the dyno, but there would be sometimes that the worker could have enough memory to have more threads.

My question is: Is there any way Sidekiq can **modify dynamically its concurrency** depending on the % of memory used by its process? If not, any recommendations on how to find a good threshold to run this in Heroku?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Unfortunately not.
2. Sidekiq generally takes 200MB on startup with a decent sized Rails app.  Any memory usage beyond that is due to your application code.  Running a full browser like PhantomJS can take a huge amount of memory.  Your best bet is to upgrade your dyno size.

Comment: Thanks Mike :) Indeed the mix of PhantomJS and RMagick is consuming lots of memory. So, I need to do a study and decide what is a good concurrency number for my workers to avoid hitting memory limits.